# How to set 'priority' of stacklayout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have heder on page where is 'MainContainer' contain rhomboid and heder with.
On heder I have user icon. By tappin on that icon user menu should show up as dropdown list.
Almost everything is fine excep that part of that menu is covered bz rhomboid.
Here is my code and images how it should be and how is it now...

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Image Source="user.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Margin="20,0,10,0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowAccountInformationCommand}" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>

                        <Image Source="kliker1.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="16"
                               WidthRequest="16"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0" />

                        <Image Source="kliker2.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="16"
                               WidthRequest="16"
                               Margin="20,0,20,0" />

                        <Image Source="kliker3.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="16"
                               WidthRequest="16"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0" />

                        <Image Source="search.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <Grid IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57">
                            <Label Text="Avatar&#x0a;Avatarevic"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            <Label Text="TST"
                                   Grid.Column="1" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57">
                            <Label Text="STATUS"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57">
                            <Label Text="UTICAJ"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57">
                            <Label Text="TOTAL"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="MainContainer"
                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                     Property=Height,Factor=0.1,Constant=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                     Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-70}">

                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      Rotation="45">
                    <!--Margin="0,-240,0,0">-->
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           BackgroundColor="#F65864"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           BackgroundColor="#00B97B"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           BackgroundColor="#F65864"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="50"
                                   Elevation="1"
                                   x:Name="RatingButtonBackground"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Height,Factor=0.59,Constant=-199}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Width,Factor=0.5,Constant=-34}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=68}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=245}"
                                   BackgroundColor="#007964"
                                   Opacity="0.5"
                                   IsVisible="False"
                                   Padding="0">

                <Label x:Name="RatingLabel"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </material:MaterialCard>

            <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="50"
                                   Elevation="1"
                                   x:Name="RatingButton"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Height,Factor=0.61,Constant=-35}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Width,Factor=0.5,Constant=-35}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=70}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=70}"
                                   BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                   Padding="2">
                <!--<material:MaterialButton.Effects>
                    <effects:LongPressedEffect />
                </material:MaterialButton.Effects>-->
            </material:MaterialCard>

            <Grid RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-70}"
                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
                  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                  RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=70}"
                  Margin="40,0,40,0">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="0"
                                       BackgroundColor="#F65864"
                                       WidthRequest="70"
                                       HeightRequest="70"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       CornerRadius="4"
                                       Elevation="1">
                    <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <!--<Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0.3,Constant=-35}"
                           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0.3,Constant=-35}"
                           Text="KREIRAJ NOVI mQR"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalOptions="Start"
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           TextColor="White" />-->

                </material:MaterialCard>

                <material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="2"
                                       BackgroundColor="#00B97B"
                                       WidthRequest="70"
                                       HeightRequest="70"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       CornerRadius="4"
                                       Elevation="1">
                    <material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ScanCommand}"/>
                    </material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                </material:MaterialCard>

                <material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="4"
                                       BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                       WidthRequest="70"
                                       HeightRequest="70"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       CornerRadius="4"
                                       Elevation="1" />
            </Grid>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: This is how it should be]

[[image: This is how it looks like now[2]]

Comment: Solution is just to change places of 'MainContainer' and Stacklayout that contains user menu in code everythig else stay the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:material="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material.Forms"
             x:Class="DunavNET.ProducPassports.Views.HomePage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="Black">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="MainContainer"
                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                     Property=Height,Factor=0.1,Constant=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                     Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-70}">

                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      Rotation="45">
                    <!--Margin="0,-240,0,0">-->
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           BackgroundColor="#BBBBBB"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0" />

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           BackgroundColor="#F65864"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Elevation="1"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           BackgroundColor="#00B97B"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>

                    <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="4"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           BackgroundColor="#F65864"
                                           WidthRequest="70"
                                           HeightRequest="70"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=10}"
                                   Text="1"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                            <Image RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-10}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                                   Source="qr_icon"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   WidthRequest="32"
                                   HeightRequest="32"
                                   Rotation="-45" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </material:MaterialCard>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Image Source="user.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Margin="20,0,10,0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowAccountInformationCommand}" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>

                        <Image Source="kliker1.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="16"
                               WidthRequest="16"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0" />

                        <Image Source="kliker2.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="16"
                               WidthRequest="16"
                               Margin="10,0,10,0" />

                        <Image Source="kliker3.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="16"
                               WidthRequest="16"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0" />

                        <Image Source="search.png"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <Grid IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                     MinimumHeightRequest="40">
                            <Label Text="Avatar&#x0a;Avatarevic"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                     MinimumHeightRequest="40">
                            <Label Text="STATUS"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                     MinimumHeightRequest="40">
                            <Label Text="UTICAJ"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                     MinimumHeightRequest="40">
                            <Label Text="TOTAL"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="50"
                                   Elevation="1"
                                   x:Name="RatingButtonBackground"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Height,Factor=0.59,Constant=-199}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Width,Factor=0.5,Constant=-34}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=68}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=245}"
                                   BackgroundColor="#007964"
                                   Opacity="0.5"
                                   IsVisible="False"
                                   Padding="0">

                <Label x:Name="RatingLabel"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </material:MaterialCard>

            <material:MaterialCard CornerRadius="50"
                                   Elevation="1"
                                   x:Name="RatingButton"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Height,Factor=0.61,Constant=-35}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                            ElementName=MainContainer,Property=Width,Factor=0.5,Constant=-35}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=70}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=70}"
                                   BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                   Padding="2">
                <!--<material:MaterialButton.Effects>
                    <effects:LongPressedEffect />
                </material:MaterialButton.Effects>-->
            </material:MaterialCard>

            <Grid RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-70}"
                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
                  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                  RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=70}"
                  Margin="40,0,40,0">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="0"
                                       BackgroundColor="#F65864"
                                       WidthRequest="70"
                                       HeightRequest="70"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       CornerRadius="4"
                                       Elevation="1">
                    <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CreateTableCommand}" />
                    </material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                    <!--<Label RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,Factor=0.3,Constant=-35}"
                           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,Factor=0.3,Constant=-35}"
                           Text="KREIRAJ NOVI mQR"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalOptions="Start"
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           TextColor="White" />-->

                </material:MaterialCard>

                <material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="2"
                                       BackgroundColor="#00B97B"
                                       WidthRequest="70"
                                       HeightRequest="70"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       CornerRadius="4"
                                       Elevation="1">
                    <material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ScanCommand}" />
                    </material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                </material:MaterialCard>

                <material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="4"
                                       BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                                       WidthRequest="70"
                                       HeightRequest="70"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       CornerRadius="4"
                                       Elevation="1" />
            </Grid>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```